# Anybody tried mosso CloudFiles with Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, storage, cloud, mosso

I'm wondering if anybody tried to integrate mosso CloudFiles with an application running on Google AppEngine (mosso does not provide testing sandbox so I cann't check for myself without registering)? Looking at the code it seems that this will not work due to httplib and urllib limitations in AppEngine environment, but maybe somebody has patched cloudfiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to implement a simple RESTful API, so there's no reason you couldn't use it from App Engine. Previously, you'd have had to write your own library to do so, using App Engine's urlfetch API, but with the release of SDK 1.1.9, you can now use urllib and httplib instead.

Comment: I was looking for some ready-made alternative to S3 + boto (which works on GAE), but it seems this is not the way. Thanks.